# Question in Symmetric Tree related to traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve a question aka "Symmetric tree"
I have come with the right solution, however I want to know why this code does not work.

I think ArrayList can contain null value and also null value can be compared in method "equals"

Anyone can see where is wrong?(I know this algorithm is not efficient way to do it)

```
    public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return true;
        }
        List<TreeNode> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TreeNode> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1 = isMirror1(root, list1);
        list2 = isMirror2(root, list2);
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    private List<TreeNode> isMirror1 (TreeNode root, List<TreeNode> list) {
        if (root == null) {
            list.add(null);
            return null;
        }
        
        list.add(root);
        isMirror1(root.left, list);
        isMirror1(root.right, list);
        
        return list;
    }
    
        private List<TreeNode> isMirror2 (TreeNode root, List<TreeNode> list) {
        if (root == null) {
            list.add(null);
            return null;
        }
        
        list.add(root);
        isMirror2(root.right, list);
        isMirror2(root.left, list);
        
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`list1.size()` and `list2.get(i)` can throw NullPointerException

Maybe you can check something like this before loop:

```
if ( list1==null || list2==null) {
    if ( list1==null && list2==null ) return true;
    return false;
}

for....
```

The code is to show the main idea, you can simplify it.

**EDIT**

first of all, you can implement your own equals method and safely use it:

```
public boolean equalsWithNulls(TreeNode a, TreeNode b) {
    if (a==b) return true;
    if ((a==null) || (b==null)) return false;
    return a.equals(b);
 }
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can store null value? I think I need to store null value in order to determine if its symmetric tree

Comment: I think it's OK to store null value inside the List.
But while comparing two Nodes, you need to check differently. I've added equalsWithNulls method, you can use it.